# Maven assembly plugin specify encoding when archiving

Tags: maven, encoding, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

Currently I´m working on "How to specify encoding of the entry names and the comment of the generated zip file". As mentioned on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#unpackOptions the encoding tag can be used to specify "the encoding to use when unpacking archives".
How can I specify the encoding to use when PACKING my archive.
That´s the critical section of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
</plugin>
```

Comment: [`encoding`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#encoding)? It's a bit unclear what you're after.

Comment: I want to specify the encoding used for the names of the entries and the comment. I don´t want to change the encoding of the files packed into the zip file itself. It is about something like [https://marcosc.com/2008/12/zip-files-and-encoding-i-hate-you/](https://marcosc.com/2008/12/zip-files-and-encoding-i-hate-you/).